# Highlight a cell based on multiple conditions of multiple cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I thought a simple OR function with a few ANDs might do what I want, but I cannot get it to work. Either I'm being stupid, or I've chosen the wrong formula.

I want to highlight a cell outside of my table based on multiple possible combinations of cells within my table.

Let's say, with the following combination of results, I want "Option 2" to be highlighted green. But I also want it to be highlighted green if C = 1 and E = no. The rest will be highlighted based on other combinations.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Only option2 need to be highlighted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a conditional formatting rule for Option 2's cell with the following formula:

```
=OR(AND(B2="yes",B3=1,B4=2,B5="no",B6="yes"),AND(B4=1,B6="no"))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks man, i thought that was it. I had speech marks around my numbers which is why mine wasn't working... So i was being stupid afterall!